# AppSettings.json gerando com as configurações incorretas

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Bom dia!
Estou trabalhando em uma API .Net Core 3.1. Esta API esta dividida em 3 ambientes, DEV, Homologação e Produção. Possuo 4 arquivos de configuração, AppSettings.json, AppSettings.Development.Json, AppSettings.Homologation.json e AppSettings.Production.Json.

Estou com o seguinte problema, nos arquivos com o nome do Ambiente, eu possuo uma string de conexão com o banco que aponta para o banco correto. Porém, ao publicar a API, o arquivo AppSettings.Json esta gerando com uma configuração a mais de conexão para o banco apontando para um endereço local que não existe.

Arquivo **AppSettings.Json**

```
   {
      "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Debug",
          "Microsoft": "Information",
          "System": "Information"
        }
      }
    }
```

Arquivo **AppSettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=192.168.1.230,1498;Initial Catalog=banco_teste;User ID=usuario_teste;Password=senha"
  },

  "AppSettings": {
    "Secret": "FE2765D5F67B9F1423DF",
    "ExpiresToken": "01 02:00"
  },

  "SQSettings": {
    "SQService": {
      "Url": "http://192.168.10.224:80/api/"
    }
  }
}
```

Arquivo **AppSettings.json gerado após a publicação** contendo a connectionString incorreta

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=banco_teste;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

O arquivo AppSettings.Development.json é gerado corretamente após a publicação, porém devido a essa string errada no arquivo AppSettings.json a conexão com o banco não funciona.

Alguem sabe o que pode ser????

Comment: Tem certeza de que você não está com o ambiente apontando para o `AppSettings.Local`?

Comment: A publicação que vc se refere é a do visual studio?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo

Answer (score 0):

descobri o erro. Tinha uma variável de ambiente setando isso nas propriedades da aplicação. Além disso, tinha um outro appsettings.json em outro ponto da aplicação com uma connectionstring local que não era utilizada. Retirei ambos e voltou a compilar corretamente. Obrigado!